# Downpicker not appearing in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am attempting to use the [Darkseal Downpicker](https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker) inside a UITableView.  I am programatically adding a UITextField and then adding the Downpicker as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

var textField = UITextField()
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
cell.selectionStyle = .none
textField.text = "TEST"
textField.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(170), height: CGFloat(30))

var dp: DownPicker!

let test1 = ["test one", "test two"]

dp = DownPicker(textField: textField, withData: test1)

cell.contentView.addSubview(dp)

return cell

}
```

If I just add the textfield:

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
```

Then it displays the text field.  However if I add the DownPicker as shown above:

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(dp)
```

I get nothing displayed, just an empty tableview.  Any help understanding why the DownPicker is not displayed would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add both ur `UITextField` and ur `DownPicker` into the `View`. If it's anything like the `UIPickerView` then your `DownPicker` will only show when you select the `UITextField`. Also you need to add your `DownPicker` to the `view` rather then the `cell`.

```
view.addSubView(dp)
```

**EDIT**

"It takes any UITextField already present in your code (including those added to a Storyboard):" - https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker

**EDIT 2**

From looking at the docs what you want to do is add yourself as the observer on the DataPicker by doing the following inside the `cellForRowAt` `func`

```
dp.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dp_selected(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

You want to add a `func` the class with `cellForRowAt` `func` inside it

```
func dp_selected(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let dp = sender as? DropDown else { return }
    if let textfield = dp.getTextField() as? UITextField {
         guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: textfield.superview) else { return }         
    }
}
```

This function will check if the sender is of type `DropDown` class and if it is will try to get the `UITextField` that it's attached to and if that is returned it will attemt to get the `IndexPath`at which it's being used at this can be `nil` if the cell is no longer visible on the screen but hopefully that will never be the case and have added a check to make sure it exists.

Comment: Harry, thank you, that was it!  They both (UITextField and DownPicker) had to be added to the subview.

Comment: Harry, by any chance do you know how to handle the change event on the DownPicker in swift?  Cannot figure it out from above link using UIControlEventValueChanged.

Comment: Thanks Harry that worked!  Set dp_selected to: func dp_selected(_ dp: DownPicker) { let selectedValue = dp.text }